# How does printf work?

Tags: c, memory, printf

I looked over but couldn't find a decent answer.

I was wondering how printf works in case like this:

```
char arr[2] = {5,6};

printf ("%d%d",arr[0],arr[1]);
```

I was thinking that printf just walks through the format and when it encouter %d for example it reads 4 bytes from the it's current position... however that's gotta be misconcepition cause that above works perfectly.

so, where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're right. But there's [argument promotion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdarg.h#Type_safety) that converts (among other things) your `char`:s into `int`:s when they are used with a "varargs" function like `printf()`.

Comment: Also, floats are promoted to doubles.

Answer (score 1):

When you say:

```
 printf ("%d%d",arr[0],arr[1]);
```

the string and the result of evaluating the two array expressions are placed on the stack and `printf` is called. `printf` takes the string from the stack and uses the % formatters in it to access the other stacked arguments in sequence. Exactly how it does that depends, as you say on the actual % value - for example, `%d` reads 4 bytes but `%f` reads 8 (for most 32-bit architectures).